# Define a function within a function or outside passing parameters

Tags: javascript

Which is the best method of defining a helper function?

I am writing a jQuery plugin, but the the question is not confined to jQuery nor how jQuery plugins work.  The plugin has the following setup code

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    /* setup */

    return this.each(function() {
        var hasMax = /* logic */;
        var maxVal = hasMax ? getMax() : undefined;
        var hasMin = /* logic */;
        var minVal = hasMin ? getMin() : undefined;

        if(hasMin || hasMax) {
            /* now do stuff */
        }
    };
};
```

I have a method that generates a message string using `hasMax`, `maxVal`, `hasMin` and `minVal`.  Where is the best/optimal/recommended place to create this function, (1) inside the return function so it can use the variables directly, (2) outside the return function and pass the parameters or (3) outside the plugin function?

I could see that there could be a difference between 1 and 2 as creating the function inside the `.each()` function would create it multiple times - does this in practise make much difference, especially as you do not have to pass variables around?

Would there be a difference between 2 and 3?

Option 1:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    /* setup */

    return this.each(function() {
        var hasMax = /* logic */;
        var maxVal = hasMax ? getMax() : undefined;
        var hasMin = /* logic */;
        var minVal = hasMin ? getMin() : undefined;

        function createMessage(){
            return /* do stuff with hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal */;
        }

        if(hasMin || hasMax) {
            /* now do stuff */
            createMessage();
        }
    };
};
```

Option 2:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    /* setup */

    function createMessage(hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal){
        return /* do stuff with hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal */;
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        var hasMax = /* logic */;
        var maxVal = hasMax ? getMax() : undefined;
        var hasMin = /* logic */;
        var minVal = hasMin ? getMin() : undefined;

        if(hasMin || hasMax) {
            /* now do stuff */
            createMessage(hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal);
        }
    };
};
```

Option 3:

```
function createMessage(hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal){
    return /* do stuff with hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal */;
}

$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    /* setup */

    return this.each(function() {
        var hasMax = /* logic */;
        var maxVal = hasMax ? getMax() : undefined;
        var hasMin = /* logic */;
        var minVal = hasMin ? getMin() : undefined;

        if(hasMin || hasMax) {
            /* now do stuff */
            createMessage(hasMax, maxVal, hasMin, minVal);
        }
    };
};
```

In the more generic case, is

```
function a(){
    var a, b, c, d;
    function b(){
        /* use a, b, c, d */
    }
    b();
}
```

better or worse than

```
function b(a, b, c, d){
    /* use a, b, c, d */
}
function a(){
    var a, b, c, d;
    b(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Note that the plugin is wrapped in a UMD wrapper so I believe that (3) will not create a global function `createMessage()`